# How to set background gradient css via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My style sheet specifies:

```
.side-grad {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #ffdd00 0%, rgba(255, 221, 0, 0) 40%, rgba(255, 221, 0, 0) 100%);
}
```

I'd like to overwrite this color getting the input from a color picker `input#color-gradient` using jquery. My understanding is that I can use decimal or hex code for the rgb component of `rgba()`, so I type this into my console:

```
>> colorGradient = $("#color-gradient").val()
"#ff00cc"
>> $(".side-grad").css("background",(
     "linear-gradient(to top," 
     + colorGradient 
     + " 0,rgba(" 
     + colorGradient 
     + ",0) 40%,rgba(" 
     + colorGradient 
     + ",0) 100%)"
     )
   );
Object { 0: <div.side-grad>, 1: <div.side-grad>, length: 2, prevObject: Object, context: HTMLDocument → example.html, selector: ".side-grad" }
```

No error is thrown, but visually nothing changes. If I set `background: #ff00cc" there's no problem and the color changes as anticipated. What am I screwing up?

Comment: Create two `css` classes, then you can switch over. using `addClass` and `removeClass`

Comment: This is for a theme visualization tool, so `.side-grad` is already the dynamic css class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot use hex in rgba.
Here's the formal syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-color#Formal_syntax